# leaflet.draw annotation, how to make it responsive when the parent svg/div width changed

Tags: leaflet

```
<div id="svgDiv">
    <svg id="svg"></svg>
  </div>
```

I'm using `leaflet plugin, leaflet.draw(annotation)`, to draw annotations like circle, line, rectangular, but when the width of parent svg/div changed, the annotations will not responsive to the right position, so can leaflet.draw do it, to be responsive